# how to make the first option active in ng-select coming inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to select the first option as default selected in each selctbox ?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gV28lK?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="question.Answer" ng-options="option for option in   question.Options">
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
<select ng-model="question.Answer" ng-init="question.Answer = question.Options[0]"  ng-options="option for option in question.Options">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `question.Answer` is initially `undefined`, that's why the default select fields are empty. To ammend this use either of two:

1. Define the default values for `question.Answer` in your controller.
2. Add the first `option` element manually like this:

   ```
   <select ng-model="question.Answer" ng-options="option for option in question.Options">
       <option value="">Pick one</option>
   </select>
   ```